# maven-jaxb2-plugin namespace issue while generating pojos

Tags: java, maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin

"I am using the maven-jaxb2-plugin in a Java Maven project to generate POJOs from XSD files. Im using a xjb file for namespaces and stuff, but sometimes on of the namespaces is not resolved. Is there a way to delay the generation until  all the namespaces have been resolved?"

Thats the namespace part in the xjb file:

```
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../xsd/2_3_1/xbau-baukasten.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings>
            <!-- Additional @XmlNs prefix declarations to take effect for this schema/package -->
            <namespace:prefix name="xbau" namespaceURI="http://www.xleitstelle.de/xbau/2/3/1" />
            <namespace:prefix name="dinspec91379" namespaceURI="urn:xoev-de:kosit:xoev:datentyp:din-spec-91379_2019-03" />
            <namespace:prefix name="xbauk" namespaceURI="http://www.xleitstelle.de/xbau/kernmodul/1/2" />
            <namespace:prefix name="xibehoerde" namespaceURI="http://www.osci.de/xinneres/behoerde/5" />
            <namespace:prefix name="xicgvz" namespaceURI="http://www.osci.de/xinneres/codes/gemeindeverzeichnis/3" />
            <namespace:prefix name="xida" namespaceURI="http://www.osci.de/xinneres/datum/2" />
            <namespace:prefix name="xilb" namespaceURI="http://www.osci.de/xinneres/lichtbild/2" />
            <namespace:prefix name="xink" namespaceURI="http://www.osci.de/xinneres/basisnachricht/5" />
            <namespace:prefix name="xoev-lc" namespaceURI="http://xoev.de/latinchars/1_1/datatypes" />
            <namespace:prefix name="xima" namespaceURI="http://www.osci.de/xinneres/meldeanschrift/3" />
        
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/workspace/source/maven/xbau/type/src/main/resources/xsd/2_3_1/xbau-baukasten.xsd{154,77}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xbauk:Dezimal.XBau' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

Like said in the question above, the build is not failing everytime. It only fails sporadically.

I tried to slow down the maven build with using the maven debug mode (-X). That fixed the error but isnt a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530239/why-cant-i-use-multiple-namespaceprefix-for-one-package-info-java-via-urnjaxb)

I've created the following [issue](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/issues/457) in jaxb-tools to make the namespace plugin capable of this since normally you can't define the prefix tag with `namespaceURI` attribute

**EDIT 06/02/2024** jaxb-tools 4.0.2 released