# Why can't I use multiple namespace:prefix for one package-info.java via urn:jaxb.jvnet.org:plugin:namespace-prefix Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

When I use these bindings:

```
<bindings schemaLocation="OrderStateService-v1.0.xsd">
    <bindings>
        <namespace:prefix name="" namespaceURI="http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_2" />
        <namespace:prefix name="soapenv" namespaceURI="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
        <namespace:prefix name="v1p0" namespaceURI="http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_0" />
        <namespace:prefix name="v1p1" namespaceURI="http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_1" />
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

while using the [namespace-prefix plugin in Maven](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-Namespace-Prefix-Plugin).

I notice I only get the first one in this list applied in my package-info.java:

```
@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_2", elementFormDefault = jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
    @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_2", prefix = "")
})
package com.intershop.iom.typesv1_2;
```

Where I would expect all of them being applied:

```
@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_2", elementFormDefault = jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
    @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_2", prefix = "")
    @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", prefix = "soapenv")
    @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_0", prefix = "v1p0")
    @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_1", prefix = "v1p1")
})
package com.intershop.iom.typesv1_2;
```

All demonstrated in branch `that-which-does-not-work` on github repo: [proof-jaxb-namespace-prefix-plugin](https://github.com/gkfirst8/proof-jaxb-namespace-prefix-plugin)

How come?

Comment: Hello there, I'm looking at your problem. If there's an issue, I'll log it in github and provide a PR to fix it if possible to fix it. We are planning a 4.0.1 release soon

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the plugin only honors the first `namespace:prefix` from the bindings.

In my particular case I could get by by finding all the targetNamespaces of each schema file and only mentioning this in the bindings like this:

```
<!-- OrderService -->
<bindings schemaLocation="OrderService-v1.1.xsd">
    <bindings>
        <namespace:prefix name="" namespaceURI="http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_2" />
    </bindings>
</bindings>
<!-- Partner -->
<bindings schemaLocation="Partner-v1.0.xsd">
    <bindings>
        <namespace:prefix name="v1p0" namespaceURI="http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_0" />
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

and so on.

Consequence is also that the attribute namespaceURI is totally useless in the bindings-file.

All demonstrated in `master`-branch of github repo [proof-jaxb-namespace-prefix-plugin](https://github.com/gkfirst8/proof-jaxb-namespace-prefix-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

By quickly modifying the plugin behaviour, I get this generated :

```java
@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_1", elementFormDefault = jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
    @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_2", prefix = ""),
    @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", prefix = "soapenv"),
    @jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://types.theberlinbakery.com/v1_0", prefix = "v1p0")
})
package com.intershop.iom.typesv1_1;
```

Is it what you're expecting ?

Also seeing the [wiki page](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-Namespace-Prefix-Plugin), the example is not expecting to read any namespaceURI : the goal is to define a prefix for the current namespace.

**EDIT 06/02/2024** : jaxb-tools 4.0.2 released

Comment: Indeed the Wiki is clear. I'm not sure where I got the namespaceURI from but it would help if you're suggestion in this answer would be a reality, thanks. (Thought my project is done with my answer.)

Comment: Created https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/issues/457 issue in jaxb-tools. I'll check it if possible to do it without breaking anything

Comment: @gkephorus : [PR created](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/pull/472)